# Same strings with special characters not equivalent with itself (in ruby), how is that possible?

Tags: ruby, string, fog

I'm uploading directly to S3 with FOG and a file has some special characters..

But when i try to

```
FOG_STORAGE.directories.get(AWS_BUCKET_TEMP).files.get(file_name)
```

it doesnt get the file =I

I debugged and found that:

```
file_name == "uploads/9d3229932694e3e71ffec98b4d7e9dd2/sóftwáred[efdv.txt" 
 => false
```

But when i print file_name, it gives me the exactly same string

```
uploads/9d3229932694e3e71ffec98b4d7e9dd2/sóftwáred[efdv.txt
```

How is that possible?

Comment: try printing the class name of both object and see if they are both strings

Comment: file_name.include?("uploads/9d3229932694e3e71ffec98b4d7e9dd2/s") returns true.. it seems that the problem is with the "éá" characters..

Comment: lulalala, both are String

Comment: Encoding issues perhaps?

Comment: @fpastore What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

Comment: @muistooshort , im using better_errors to debug, but it seems to be the same encoding: file_name.encoding => #<Encoding:UTF-8> and "uploads/9d3229932694e3e71ffec98b4d7e9dd2/sóftwáred[efdv.txt" => #<Encoding:UTF-8>

Comment: Do they have the same length? Have you tried comparing them character-by-character to see where the difference lies?